# how can we create a position for the 2.0.1.1 opencart version

Tags: opencart, opencart2.x

Opencart has a four layout left ,right Top and a Bottom.Adding new custom positions manually is not impossible of course, but ideally that needs to be done at the core.

Something like "header-bottom" or "footer-top" would be very useful for many modules, like "Menus" and "Slideshows".

how can we create a position like as above  for the 2.0.1.1 opencart version

please help me thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I m making

> footer_top    POSITION similarly you can make any position
>
> Add code in 
>   opencart2\catalog\controller\common\home.php  line 15(you can
>   understand where to put this line or ask it)

```
$data['footer_top'] = $this->load->controller('common/footer_top');
```

> And Add this code in opencart2\catalog\view\theme\default\template\common\home.tpl
>   on line 13

```
 <div id="content" class="col-sm-12"><?php echo $footer_top; ?></div>
```

> copy ->  opencart2\catalog\controller\common\content_top.php
>
> to ----> opencart2\catalog\controller\common\footer_top.php
>
> And change line 44

from

```
$modules = $this->model_design_layout->getLayoutModules($layout_id, 'content_top');
```

to

```
$modules = $this->model_design_layout->getLayoutModules($layout_id, 'footer_top');
```

> Open opencart2\admin\view\template\design\layout_form.tpl and add this
>   code In select position dropdown options

```
    <?php if ($layout_module['position'] == 'footer_top') { ?>
            <option value="footer_top" selected="selected">footer top</option>
            <?php } else { ?>
            <option value="footer_top">footer top</option>
            <?php } ?>
```

And Add below code after

```
html += '    < option value="content_top"><?php echo $text_content_top; ?>< /option>';
```

line in addmodule() function

```
html += '    < option value="footer_top">footer top< /option>';
```

And check in Position

opencart2/admin/index.php?route=design/layout/edit&token=7ddf86dsfdsfsdfdsfsdfdsfsdf5df&layout_id=1